# What is the longest duration a team didn't register a shot on goal in the Stanley Cup Playoffs?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, records, nhl, stanley-cup

The Pittsburgh Penguins didn't have a shot on goal for about 37 minutes in game 1 of the 2016-17 Stanley Cup finals. Although the Penguins fired a number of shots, they all either went wide or got blocked, and hence non of them counted as a shot on goal.

It's uncommon to not have a shot on goal for an entire period. Did the Penguins break the record for the longest time between 2 shots on goal, in the history of Stanley Cup finals or Stanley Cup playoffs?

If so, please state which team had this record previously.

Answer (score 5):

I googled "[NHL no shots in a period](https://www.google.com/search?q=nhl+no+shots+in+a+period)" and found this:

- [Penguins recover to defeat Predators in Game 1 of Stanley Cup Final](https://www.nhl.com/news/nashville-predators-pittsburgh-penguins-game-1-stanley-cup-final-recap/c-289662896?tid=287345494) (NHL website):

> Pittsburgh did not have a shot on goal in the second period. Nashville became the first team to hold an opponent to zero shots in a period during a Stanley Cup Final since the NHL began tracking shots on goal in 1957-58.

- The same information was mentioned on [NHL Public Relations twitter](https://twitter.com/PR_NHL/status/869379578405560320).

Considering that the source is the NHL, I consider the information reliable (and verifiable). Thus, it seems that this is the longest duration a team didn't register a shot on goal during the *Stanley Cup Finals*.

(This only answers the first part of your question - which is how it [was stated originally](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/16217/revisions). It would be nice to also find records for Stanley Cup playoffs and for regular season.)